# Changes made in sql query in excel reflects changes only on single sheet

Tags: sql, excel

I have a connection where I retrieve different stock data based on their stock symbols. There are thousands of stock symbols(eg.AWK, POWI,PG,A etc). I have 10 sheets in excel. When I go to connection property and change stock symbol it only works on the sheet I am at the moment.I want changes made to all the sheets.
[image]

What should I do so that changing the stock symbol for once reflects results in all sheets?

I want to update the below connections they have all same strings. I have to open each of them and change stock symbol.How do I change someting in one query and it affects all others too

[image]

Comment: Have you clicked on Data > Refresh All? BTW it's probably easier to get your connection to use a value in a sheet cell for the stock symbol - rather than editing your connection each time you want to change it

Comment: @NickW I didn't get you. When I pressed refresh all it doesn't change other sheets. Did you mean press refresh all after I change the stock symbol?

Comment: Yes - having changed your connection to use the new stock symbol, have you clicked Refresh All? Also, I assume that all your sheets use the same connection?

Comment: @NickW Yes after changing the symbol I clicked on refresh all it did not change any other sheet.

Comment: @NickW any other way you could help me, Nick. I am tired of switching tabs and changing queries.

Comment: Just trying to be absolutely clear on what you are doing... When you say "switching tabs and changing queries" do you mean that on each tab you have to change the query again to the new ticker symbol? If so, doesn't this mean that you have different connections for each tab? If you do then the best solution is my suggestion in my first comment - add a sheet where you select the ticker symbol you want to use and then update all your connections (once) to use this cell. Having done this, when you select a new ticker symbol in the cell and hit Refresh All, all the sheets will update.

Comment: You could also add VBA so that when the a new value is selected then the Refresh All is run automatically

Comment: @NickW I have 10 different sheets(TABS). Each sheet has this query......SELECT StockQuoteDaily.QuoteDate, StockQuoteDaily.StockSymbol, StockQuoteDaily.OpenPrice, StockQuoteDaily.HighPrice, StockQuoteDaily.LowPrice, StockQuoteDaily.ClosePrice, StockQuoteDaily.Volume
FROM ModelT.dbo.StockQuoteDaily StockQuoteDaily
WHERE (StockQuoteDaily.StockSymbol='HIBB')
ORDER BY StockQuoteDaily.QuoteDate DESC

Comment: I am doing something that requires changing-->( StockQuoteDaily.StockSymbol='HIBB') . When I am done with HIBB I change it with different stock symbol. say XRX. So what I have to enter XRX by switiching 10 sheets.How to do it only once so that all all the changes get reflected to all the 10 sheets.

Comment: @NickW Did you understand now?

Comment: @NickW I have edited the question I think I have different connections.

Comment: Yes - each sheet has a different connection/query. Therefore I would look to parameterise them all - quite a bit of work initially but much easier to use once you've done it. Lots of articles on the web about parameterising Excel queries but try here as a starting point (select the version of Excel you have and scroll down to the "Use data from a cell as a parameter value" section): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-a-parameter-query-addf7cb7-ddf0-442f-a60c-cd7280e201bd#ID0EDABAAA=Newer_versions

Comment: @NickW Could you ping me on Gmail(deep1161996@gmail.com) and help me out using teamviewer. I am not able to understand the fix.